# Angular error with String Replace function using interpolation in HTML

Tags: angular

In my Angular application, I am trying to display file name from complete file path.

```
<ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem="dataItem">            
        <a style="text-decoration: underline !Important;" href="javascript:void(0)" (click)="downloadFile(dataItem)">{{dataItem.file.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '')}}</a>
</ng-template>
```

`dataItem.file.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '')` works when I use in component class but fails in html with interpolation.

I get error as:

```
Parser Error: Unexpected token / at column 35 in [{{dataItem.file.replace(/^.*[\\\], '')}}] in ng:///AppModule/MyComponent.html@24:130 ("-decoration: underline !Important;" href="javascript:void(0)" (click)="downloadFile(dataItem)">[ERROR ->]{{dataItem.file.replace(/^.*[\\\], '')}}</a>
```

Is there anything wrong with this line in the interpolation ?  Any pointers ?

```
{{dataItem.file.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '')}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following interpolation, you are creating a `RegExp` object, which is not allowed in that context:

```
{{ dataItem.file.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '') }}
```

You can wrap the call in a method of the component:

```
formatPath(path: string): string {
  return path.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
}
```

and call the method in the template:

```
{{ formatPath(dataItem.file) }}
```

Comment: This is Great. Thanks @ConnorsFan